# vba change events

Tags: excel, vba

the below code isnt working

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim thecurrentcell 
thecurrentcell = ActiveCell.AddressLocal

If thecurrentcell = "$E$45" And thecurrentcell = "$E$48" Then

If LCase(Worksheets("Check").Range("E47").Value) = "yes" And LCase(Worksheets("Check").Range("E48").Value) = "yes" Then
        Rows("49:59").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        
ElseIf LCase(Worksheets("Check").Range("E47").Value) = "yes" And LCase(Worksheets("Check").Range("E48").Value) = "No" Then
        Rows("49:59").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        
ElseIf LCase(Worksheets("Check").Range("E47").Value) = "No" And LCase(Worksheets("Check").Range("E48").Value) = "Yes" Then
        Rows("49:59").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
ElseIf LCase(Worksheets("Check").Range("E47").Value) = "No" And LCase(Worksheets("Check").Range("E48").Value) = "No" Then
Rows("49:59").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else:
        End If
End If
```

Comment: Please see [ask] and [reprex]. I think you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: the above code isnt working

Comment: We need more information.  What is it doing that is incorrect?  What line is throwing the error?  More than `the above code isnt working`

Comment: I want to hide rows if value of row47 and row48 is "No", if anyone of the value of row47 and row48 is "yes" then it should unhide the rows. By default rows 49:59 will be hidden

Comment: how can any string the is returned with `Lcase` be equal to a string that has upper case letters: `"Yes"` and `"No"` should be `"yes"` and `"no"`

Comment: i made that correction as well, still it isn't working

Comment: `thecurrentcell` cannot be *both* "$E$45" *and* "$E$48"  Where do you get the value of that variable from?  Your code is incomplete.

Comment: can you please edit the code and send it or provide a better code for this situation

Comment: It's your code - *you* edit it.

Comment: im not getting it

Comment: Most likely you have `thecurrentcell = Target.Address` previously in your code ... please provide your entire code snippet, or at least a [reprex]. So we don't have to guess about code we can't see.

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim thecurrentcell
thecurrentcell = ActiveCell.AddressLocal

Comment: `If thecurrentcell = "$E$45" Or thecurrentcell = "$E$48" Then`

Comment: `thecurrentcell = ActiveCell.AddressLocal`.... `ActiveCell` is not the same as `Target`.

Comment: please read thecurrentcell = "$E$47" or thecurrentcell = "$E$48" then

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim addr As String, v1, v2
    
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub 'only processing single-cell changes
    
    addr = Target.Address(False, False) 'not ActiveCell
    
    If addr = "E45" Or addr = "E48" Then

        v1 = LCase(Worksheets("Check").Range("E47").Value) 'or Me.Range("E47") if the same sheet...
        v2 = LCase(Worksheets("Check").Range("E48").Value)
    
        If v1 = "yes" Or v2 = "yes" Then
            Me.Rows("49:59").EntireRow.Hidden = True  
        ElseIf v1 = "no" And v2 = "no" Then
            Me.Rows("49:59").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If the values of E45 & E47 rows are no it should hide the rows from 49:59 , which isn't happening

Comment: Your posted code checks E47 and E48, not E45 and E47.  The change you need should be clear.

Comment: Sorry if the values of E47 and E48 are no then it should hide rows 49:59

Comment: Then it's correct: if it's not working for you then you need to do some debugging to see what the problem is.

Comment: The code you shared is hiding rows if both values are no

Comment: Yes my question is if any one of value has yes it should unhide rows , if both values are no then it should hide rows, I tried the code you shared in case of both nos it is not hiding rows

Comment: OK try my edit above.  It's not clear from your question whether Yes/No are the only possible values for those two cells?